# AngularJS directive discoverability in templates

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm rather impressed with AngularJS, but one of a few things that is bothering me is that it isn't as easy as some other frameworks to discover the linkages between code and templates.  For example, a template for a directive can contain many other directives, and those directives can be tags, attributes, even id or class names, so they are not immediately visible when looking at the template file.  The only way I know to discover all the directives in a large template file is to painstakingly look at every line of markup.  I suppose I could write a program to discover all the directives I define and then search all my templates for uses of those directives, but is there another way?

Comment: I guess the 'other' way would be to not have a large template file to begin with. Start by abstracting out common bits of markup in another template or directive.

Comment: You can adopt a convention for using directive with attributes or element or class and stick by it. You can also prefix all your directives, how AngularJS does using `ng`